# Dictionary of 4-D numpy array: how to optimize?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a problem of performances in inizializing a dictionary of 4-D numpy tensor.

I have a list of coefficients names:

```
cnames = ['CN', 'CM', 'CA', 'CY', 'CLN' ...];
```

that is not fixed-size (it depends from upper code).
For each coefficient i have to generate a 4-D tensor [nalpha X nmach X nbeta X nalt] of zeros (for preallocation purposes), so I do:

```
#Number of coefficients
numofc = len(cnames);

final_data = {};
#I have to generate <numofc> 4D matrixes
for i in range(numofc):
    final_data[cnames[i]]=n.zeros((nalpha,nmach,nbeta,nalt));
```

<strike>each index is an integer between 10 and 30.</strike>
each index is an integer between 100 and 200

This takes like 4 minutes. How can I speed up this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A more pythonic solution (bit faster) would be: `final_data = {cname : np.zeros((nalpha,nmach,nbeta,nalt)) for cname in cnames}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted should not take 4 minutes to run (unless `cnames` is extremely large or you have very little RAM and is forced to use swap space).

```
import numpy as np

cnames = ['CN', 'CM', 'CA', 'CY', 'CLN']*1000
nalpha,nmach,nbeta,nalt = 10,20,30,40
#Number of coefficients
numofc = len(cnames)

final_data = {}
#I have to generate <numofc> 4D matrixes
for i in range(numofc):
    final_data[cnames[i]]=np.zeros((nalpha,nmach,nbeta,nalt))
```

Even if `cnames` has 5000 elements, it should still take only on the order of a couple seconds:

```
% time test.py
real    0m4.559s
user    0m0.856s
sys 0m3.328s
```

The semicolons at the end of statements suggests you have experience in some other language. Be careful of translating commands from that language line-by-line into NumPy/Python. Coding in NumPy as one would in C is a recipe for slowness.

In particular, try to avoid updating elements in an array element-by-element. This works fine in C, but is very slow with Python. NumPy achieves speed by delegating to functions coded in Fortran or Cython or C or C++. By updating arrays element-by-element you are using Python loops which are not as fast.

Instead, try to rephrase your computation in terms of operations on whole arrays (or at least, slices of arrays).

I have probably speculated too much on the cause of the problem. You need to [profile your code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), and then, if you want more specific help, post the result of the profile plus the problematic code (most helpfully in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked up and i was wrong about the tensor sizes.

Each index is between 100 and 180. 
4 minutes could be ok in this case?

Comment: @TiD91 - If you have enough ram, it should take only seconds. What's probably happening is that you're running out of ram and starting to use swap space.  A 100x100x100x100 array of int64's will take up ~760MB, while a 200x200x200x200 array of the same will take up ~12GB.  If memory is mostly full, but you have enough memory to hold one array, you won't get a `MemoryError`. Instead, your OS will swap the contents of your RAM to disk to make room for the new array. Reading and writing several GB to disk is slow.